# how to embed Video from Live website in Android app

Tags: android, web, webview

here is  [a link](http://www.aljazeera.com/watch_now/)!
This link has Video and i want to display only video in my Android app. I think this website haven't provided any xml service so that we can use it, Is there any way to show only Video from this link to android app.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hii ali you want to play video in your android app it can be do by two ways .
you can use your default youtube app to play the video or you can play it in your browser by following way.

```
                if (isAppInstalled("com.google.android.youtube")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse("vnd.youtube://" + b.getString("video")));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Toast.makeText(this,
                    // "To view this Video you must install the youtube application in your device..",
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse("http://m.youtube.com/watch?v="
                                    + b.getString("video"))));
                    finish();
                }
```

It worked for me
If it worked please vote

Comment: OK Deepak i'm checking, wht is b in ur case?

Comment: Actually main problem is Video on the Website is not from YouTube, they have their own Live video. Main question is how i can use Video of that website and use it in android app.

Comment: actually it is the video code of youtube b.getString("video")

Comment: I have also tried the link of the video which is mentioned js of html in VideoView but not worked.

Comment: mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

mVideoView.setVideoPath("rtsp://YOURCOMPUTER_SERVER_IP_ADDR:5544/");
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

Comment: Yes i have tried this, n also using Vitamio lib which support .m3u8 format but no luck. thing left to do that how i can pick that div which contains video and use it android WebView.

Comment: WebView webview = new WebView(this); 

        String htmlString = "<html> <body> <embed src=\"http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cxLG2wtE7TM\"; type=application/x-shockwave-flash width="+320+" height="+400+"> </embed> </body> </html>";

        webview.loadData(htmlString ,"text/html", "UTF-8");